# How to read alpha channel from .webm video using ffmpeg in c++

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, alpha, webm

## Background

I have a `.webm` file (pix_fmt: yuva420p) converted from `.mov` video file in order to reduce file size and I would like to read the video data using c++, so I followed using this [repo](https://github.com/bartjoyce/video-app) as a reference.

This works perfectly on `.mov` video.

## Problem

By using same repo, however, there is no alpha channel data (pure zeros on that channel) for .webm video but I can get the alpha data from `.mov` video.

Apparently many [people](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8468) already noticed that after the video conversion, `ffmpeg` somehow detect video as yuv420p + `alpha_mode : 1` and thus alpha channel is not used but there is no one discuss about workaround of this.

I tried forcing pixel format during this part to use `yuva420p` but that just broke the whole program.

```
  // Set up sws scaler
    if (!sws_scaler_ctx) {
        auto source_pix_fmt = correct_for_deprecated_pixel_format(av_codec_ctx->pix_fmt);
        sws_scaler_ctx = sws_getContext(width, height, source_pix_fmt,
                                        width, height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB0,
                                        SWS_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }
```

I also verified my video that it contains alpha channel using other [source](https://rotato.app/tools/transparent-video) so I am sure there is alpha channel in my `webm` video but I cannot fetch the data using ffmpeg.

Is there a way to fetch the alpha data? Other video format or using other libraries work as well as long as it does have some file compression but I need to access the data in c++.

**Note**: This is the code I used for converting video to `webm`

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pix_fmt yuva420p output.webm
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to force the decoder.

Set the following before `avformat_open_input()`

```
AVCodec *vcodec;
vcodec = avcodec_find_decoder_by_name("libvpx-vp9");
av_fmt_ctx->video_codec = vcodec;
av_fmt_ctx->video_codec_id = vcodec->id;
```

You don't need to set pixel format or any scaler args.

This assumes that your libavcodec is linked with `libvpx`.

Comment: I'm not sure why but using "libvpx-vp9" returns NULL. 

Using "vp9" works but it gives the same codec as what it is automatically detected (`AV_CODEC_ID_VP9`) and gives the same result.

Comment: `vp9` is the internal ffmpeg decoder. `libvpx-vp9` requires libvpx.

Comment: I do have libvpx in my ffmpeg as in the setting here `--enable-libvpx`. 
When using `ffmpeg -codecs` it also shows:  `DEV.L. vp9  Google VP9 (decoders: vp9 libvpx-vp9 ) (encoders: libvpx-vp9 )`

So I think there definitely has vpx installed, but maybe it is not used in the c++ somehow..? 

Do I need to include vpx library?

Comment: Your compiled code isn't calling the binary. It's linked against libav*. Identify the libavcodec.a or .so that it's linked with and run ldd on libavcodec lib if it's shared.

Comment: Just for clarification, does libvpx-vp9 works on Windows (because this is what I worked on).  And if so, do you know how can I link/verify that it is linked on Windows? (I might open this issue as another post since it is getting off-topic of original question)

Comment: You can use https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies to check. libvpx works on Windows.